# looking for ag grid CellRendererParams OnClick params typescript type definitions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to identify the typescript type of the parameter passed into the ag grid's cellRendererParams.onClick method. I do not like having `any` types but I have spent too much of my company's time trying to track down the exact type.

Can someone please
a) identify this particular type,
b) point me to where these types are defined, and
c) a full definition of the properties of the `CellRendererParam`? (While doing this exercise for another type, I discovered that it actually has *validators*, which is huge! But my d.ts file defines this type as `any`.)

This is how a previous developer defined it.
[image]

I'm trying to remove this `any`:
[image]

What I have tried so far:
I have poured through all the pages I can find on the ag-grid pages, including https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#complex-cell-renderer-example.